# How to include a ng-template from another file?

Tags: angularjs

I have a html file with several "text/ng-template" script tags, like this (templates.html):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1">
    ng-template 1
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2">
    ng-template 2
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template3">
    ng-template 3
</script>
```

I want to include one template from "templates.html" but not all, I would like to find something like:

```
<ng-include src="'templates.html#template1'"></div>
```

It's possible? exists any other third party directive to do it?

PD: I know that I can extract each ng-template on a separate file (template1.html, template2.html, ...) and load each with ng-include, but I have very much templates and I need to group it.